# Schedule tests to verify if a deployed streamlit app is working or not

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, streamlit

I have created a streamlit app, deployed it and shared it with few other people. In order to make sure that the app is running smooth, I manually login to the app once every 4 hours, enter few input values and check if all the tabs in the app are getting populated or not? Is there a way where I can have a mechanism which can check if the app is working fine by entering the input values and verifying all the tabs that my app have in an automated way.

Comment: You can probably a scraper such as [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on [automated testing of streamlit apps using seleniumbase](https://blog.streamlit.io/testing-streamlit-apps-using-seleniumbase/). My post (code copied below) focuses on pixel-perfect display between code runs, but it could easily be extended to testing inputs using other features of [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/):

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
import cv2
import time


class ComponentsTest(BaseCase):
    def test_basic(self):

        # open the app and take a screenshot
        self.open("http://localhost:8501")

        time.sleep(10)  # give leaflet time to load from web
        self.save_screenshot("current-screenshot.png")

        # test screenshots look exactly the same
        original = cv2.imread(
            "visual_baseline/test_package.test_basic/first_test/screenshot.png"
        )
        duplicate = cv2.imread("current-screenshot.png")

        assert original.shape == duplicate.shape

        difference = cv2.subtract(original, duplicate)
        b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)
        assert cv2.countNonZero(b) == cv2.countNonZero(g) == cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0
```